# React data components table does not render HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

https://github.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components package does not allow sending html into a `td` cell. See:

[image]

[image]

My goal is hyperlink to that product.

My use is:

```
import React from 'react';
var DataTable = require('react-data-components').DataTable;
import PlainTable from './PlainTable'


class ReduxDataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

    processHeaders(){
      var columns = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.props.data.headers.length; i++){
          var header = this.props.data.headers[i];
          var item = {title: header, prop: header};
          columns.push(item);
      }
      return columns;
    }

    render() {
        var dataList = this.props.data.data;
        console.log("datalist is", dataList);
        console.log("datalist length is", dataList.length);
        var headerList = this.processHeaders();

        if(dataList.length > 2) {
          return (
              <DataTable
                keys="name"
                columns={headerList}
                initialData={dataList}
                initialPageLength={20}
                initialSortBy={{ prop: headerList[0].title, order: 'descending' }}
                pageLengthOptions={[ 20, 60, 120 ]}
              />
          );
        }
        else {
          return (
              <PlainTable
                headers={headerList}
                rows={dataList}
              />
          );
        }
    }
}

export { ReduxDataTable as default };
```

then just

```
return (
  <div className="card">
    <h2 className="style-1">Detailed Report</h2>
    <br/>
      <h2 className="style-1:after">Data about products </h2>
      <ReduxDataTable data={data}/>
 </div>
)
```

Plain table is a `<table>` in case there's few products.

The package does not show any "htmlTrue" option, as searching "html" show nothing useful. I'm getting the same issue with any html at all:

[image]

I'm not opposed to forking it, but is there a simple way to use this package and declare html here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't use that component, but looking through the code, it seems that you can use a `render` function to do what you need. See here: https://github.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components/blob/3d092bd375da0df9428ef02f18a64d056a2ea5d0/src/Table.js#L13

See the example here https://github.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components/blob/master/example/table/main.js#L17

Relevant code snippet:

```
const renderMapUrl =
  (val, row) =>
    <a href={`https://www.google.com/maps?q=${row['lat']},${row['long']}`}>
      Google Maps
    </a>;

const tableColumns = [
  { title: 'Name', prop: 'name' },
  { title: 'City', prop: 'city' },
  { title: 'Street address', prop: 'street' },
  { title: 'Phone', prop: 'phone', defaultContent: '<no phone>' },
  { title: 'Map', render: renderMapUrl, className: 'text-center' },
];

return (
  <DataTable
    className="container"
    keys="id"
    columns={tableColumns}
    initialData={data}
    initialPageLength={5}
    initialSortBy={{ prop: 'city', order: 'descending' }}
    pageLengthOptions={[ 5, 20, 50 ]}
  />
);
```

Try adding the `render` property to your `dataList`. Maybe something like this

```
var dataList = this.props.data.data;
for (let i=0; i<dataList.length; i++)
    dataList[i].render = function(val, row) {return (
        <a href={row.href}>row.title</a>
    )}
```